# BigQuery: over-clause partitioned by date returns same values for different dates

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm working with Google Analytics Data (nested fields).
I'm trying to get the total revenue ('revenue_day_total') for every day but the following query, which includes OVER and PARTITION, returns the same value for 'revenue_day_total' for different dates (row 1 in window function).

```
SELECT
  date,
  device.deviceCategory AS device,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(customDimensions) WHERE index = 26 LIMIT 1) AS system,  
  channelGrouping AS channel,   
  SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) / 1000000 AS revenue_grouped,  
  (SELECT ROUND(SUM(totals.totalTransactionRevenue) OVER (PARTITION BY date) / 1000000, 2) FROM `<project>.<dataset>.ga_sessions_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AND   FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND totals.visits = 1 LIMIT 1)  AS revenue_day_total,    
FROM
  `<project>.<dataset>.ga_sessions_*`
 WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND totals.visits = 1 
GROUP BY
  date,
  device,
  system,
  channel
```

results:

[image: same value for different dates]

My goal is to get the following values for 'revenue_day_total' for the different dates:
[image]

I'm not sure how to write the query to get the correct current 'revenue_day_total' for the different dates. How can i make the over clause dynamic based on the dimension date (which is a string, e.g. '20191230')

Comment: please provide sample results, and maybe sample data

Comment: @FelipeHoffa
thanks for replying. I edited my initial post with a result and goal image. I'm not sure how to append a database, hope it's good enough

Comment: In order to see why you are getting these results, it would be good if you could share some data from the source table, perhaps a small example of the source table, hereafter A, and then the result with your query to this table A. That way, we can figure out why you got those results and maybe replicate them and try to solve it.